# Windows7 Re-Install - SSD not booting - Windows Boot Manager does - PC much slower

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, performance

I have formatted my PC only once. Before the re-install of Windows, I had the SSD as the 1st boot priority and everything worked fine. After the re-install, Windows Boot Manager is the first and unchangeable (PC doesn't boot) option. Here are my system specs:

```
M/B: Gigabyte Z87M-D3H RETAIL
CPU: Intel i7 4790
SSD: TOSHIBA OCZ VT180 240 GB
HDD: Western Digital 2TB RED NAS SATEM
```

So today I thought I would do a fresh install of Windows 7 on my SDD (done previously). So the usual steps are where taken.

I did notice unlike previously that the time between pressing the power button and getting to the user-login screen is much longer like 10 or more seconds. Also if I minimize a (folder) window I can see that it's lagging.

Before formatting, my PC would boot lightning fast. The four orbs that form the Windows flag made a little spin and before forming the flag I was on the user-login screen.

Now the orbs complete the flag and it kind of sits there for a couple of seconds.

I really don't know why it's so much slower than before. Hope you can save me.

Comment: Did you update your drivers after install completed?

Comment: I managed to fix it (i think). I updated the drivers and everything now is good. 

Also for this: "Also if i minimize a (folder)window i can see that it's lagging." it was something so simple. I just changed the theme to windows aero. Yes i know ...  

If you guys have the same problem and you cant fix it by the same way...I don't know.

Case closed.